# Angular 7 CanActivate Guards Failing over

Tags: angular, angular7, canactivate

I've got CanActivate guards on all my routes and they are failing over.

For instance, I have two guards:

```
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private as: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate() {
        if (this.as.isLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        }

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);

        return false;
     }
    }

export class IsAdminGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private us: UserService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate() {
        if (this.us.isAdmin()) {
            return true;
        }

        this.router.navigate(['/home']);

        return false;
    }
}
```

And my route guards

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard, IsAdminGuard]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
});
```

What's happening is that if `AuthenticationGuard` fails, it will *sometimes* check `IsAdminGuard` and instead of routing someone to `/login` when they are not authenticated, they are sent to `/home` which sends them to a different error page because they are not authenticated and are not an admin and the guards should have kicked them out on the first fail.

I can reproduce the issue 100% of the time if I remove the authentication jwt that `AuthenticationService` checks when it calls `isLoggedIn()`, refresh the `/home` route and can trace the `AuthenticationGuard` returning `false` and *still* calling `IsAdminGuard`

Here is the code for `isLoggedIn()`

```
isLoggedIn = () => {
    const token = this.get();
    const decoded = this.decode(token);

    return token && this.isNotExpired(decoded);
};  

decode = (token: string) => {
    const validToken = () => parts.length < 3
    const parts = token ? token.split('.') : '';

    if (!token || validToken()) {
        return '{}';
    }

    const payload = validToken() ? parts[1] : '{}';

    return JSON.parse(atob(payload));
};

private isNotExpired = (decodedToken) => this.getExpiryFrom(decodedToken) > new Date();

private getExpiryFrom = (decodedToken) => new Date(decodedToken.exp * 1000);
```

thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you change the order of the guards in the CanActivate Array?

Comment: Is `isLoggedIn()` async?

Comment: @Phix it is synchronous - it just checks the expiry on the auth token

Comment: can you post it here just to cover all bases

Comment: @BenSteward that's hilarious, if I flip them it works fine. though that's not the logical order they should be operating in

Comment: It’s probably checking both, so even though the first fails, it is still hitting the second and then navigating to home.

Comment: @Phix added the code for you

Comment: @BenSteward correct - adding logs to the two fail blocks of each guard shows they're still both getting called and returning false

Comment: FWIW, in my authguards I don’t do routing. I just call the logout function from my authservice, so routing is handled uniformly and any anomalies are cleaned up.

Comment: That's a great suggestion that I can get behind. I'm still miffed as my understanding is that these shouldn't cascade - but I'm new to the angular

Comment: @BenSteward that did the trick. I pulled the routing logic down into authorization service.  if you want to add a new answer or adjust yours a bit, I can check it off - thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 1):

Consider working in a short circuit to your isAdmin guard that rechecks the authentication status. That way the authentication truthiness will never be overridden by how your isAdmin truthiness turns out. It may seem redundant, but it would work.

Comment: yeah I've tried that and it definitely works - though I did want to keep each guard atomic - was hoping to avoid coupling them together and maybe expose an underlying issue